# SyntaxError: invalid syntax Python 3.5 when trying to print in python, even with a simple print("Hello World")

Tags: python, syntax-error

I just finished deleting a bunch of files off my desktop and other misc. folders. I just re-opened my project that I have been working on and now it won't print, even with a simple 'Hello World' line 144.

I have opened a new python project and I just printed("hello world") and it works fine, so I tried coping my code to that same sheet and saving it as a different name and I get the same error.

This is the code I am using below; print is all the way at the bottom.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as dreader
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser
from tkinter import *


# Sets the max rows that can be displayed
# when the program is executed
pd.options.display.max_rows = 200



# df is the name of the dataframe, it is 
# reading the csv file containing data loaded
# from yahoo finance(Date,Open,High,Low,Close
# volume,adj close,)the name of the ticker
# is placed before _data.csv i.e. the ticker aapl
# would have a csv file named aapl_data.csv.
df = pd.read_csv("cde_data.csv")


# resets the index back to the pandas default
# i.e. index starts at 0 for the first row and
# 1 for the second and continues by one till the
# end of the data in the above csv file. 
df.reset_index()



# the following code will allow for filtering of the datafram
# based on the year, day of week (dow), and month. It then gets
# applied to the dataframe and then can be used to sort data i.e
# print(df[(df.year == 2015) & (df.month == 5) & (df.dow == 4)])
# which will give you all the days in the month of May(df.month == 5), 
# that fall on a Thursday(df.dow == 4), in the year 2015 
# (df.year == 2015)
#
#      Month          Dow                      Year
# January    = 1  Monday    = 1  The year will be dispaly in a four
# February   = 2  Tuesday   = 2  digit format i.e. 2015
# March      = 3  Wednesday = 3
# April      = 4  Thursday  = 4
# May        = 5  Friday    = 5
# June       = 6
# July       = 7
# August     = 8
# September  = 9
# October    = 10
# November   = 11
# December   = 12
def year(x):
    return(x.year)
def dow(x):
    return(x.isoweekday())
def month(x):
    return(x.month)
df.Date            = df.Date.apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
df['year']         = df.Date.apply(year)
df['dow']          = df.Date.apply(dow)
df['month']        = df.Date.apply(month)


# The code below has a total of five sections all labeled by number.
# They are #1, #2, #3, #4, #5. Number one adds new columns to the df
# and populates them with data, number two filters out all the days
# that the market went down or flat for the day, number three filters
# out all of the days that the market went up or flat, number four 
# filters all of the days that  the market went up or down, and
# number five drops the excess columns and concats steps #2, #3, & #4. 


# 1
# there are five columns that are being added, up_down, up, down, 
# flat, and %chg. up, down, and flat are temporary and will be 
# deleted later on the other two up_down, and %chg will be permeant.
# The up_down column is derived from taking the 'close' column minus the
# 'open'column, this tells you how much the stock has moved for the day.
# The 'up' column is temporary and has a value of 'up' for all the rows
# of the DataFrame df. The 'down' column is temporary and has a value of  
# 'down' for all the rows of the DataFrame df. The 'down' column is   
# temporary and has a value of 'flat' for all the rows of the DataFrame 
# df. The '%chg' column is calculated by taking the results of the 
# 'up_down' divided by the 'close' column, and then times 100, which
# turns it into a percentage show what percent the stock moved up or 
# down for the day. All of the columns added below are added to the 
# DataFrame called df, which contains a a csv file(see code lines 14-20
# for information on the csv file contained in the DataFrame df). 
df['up_down']      = df['Close'] - df['Open'] 
df['up']           = 'up'   
df['down']         = 'down'
df['flat']         = 'flat'
df['%chg']         = ((df['up_down']/df['Close'])*100)      


# 2
# df column[up_down] is first filtered on the greater than zero
# criteria from the year 1984 on up and then is turned into df2.
# If the up_down column is greater than zero than this means that 
# the stock went up. Next df3 is set = to df2['up'], df3 now holds 
# just the days where the asset went up  
df2= (df[(df.year > 1984) & (df.up_down > 0)])
df3 = df2['up']



# 3
# df column[up_down] is first filtered on the less than zero
# criteria from the year 1984 on up and then is turned into df4.
# If the up_down column is less than zero than this means that 
# the stock went Down. Next df5 is set = to df4['down'], df5 now holds 
# just the days where the asset went down 
df4= (df[(df.year > 1984) & (df.up_down < 0)])
df5 = df4['down']



# 4
# df column[up_down] is first filtered on the equal to zero
# criteria from the year 1984 on up and then is turned into df6.
# If the up_down column is equal to zero than this means that 
# the stock did not move. Next df7 is set = to df6['flat'],df5 
# now holds just the days where the asset did not move at all 
df6= (df[(df.year > 1984) & (df.up_down == 0)])
df7 = df6['flat']



# 5
# The code below starts by droping the columns 'up', 'down', and 'flat'.
# These were temporary and were used to help filter data in the above
# code in sections two, three, and four. Finally we concat the 
# DataFrames df, df3, df5, and df7. We now have new 'up', 'down' and
# 'flat' columns that only display up, down, or flat when the criteria 
# is true.
df = df.drop(['up'], axis = 1)
df = df.drop(['down'], axis = 1)
df = df.drop(['flat'], axis = 1)
df = pd.concat([df,df3,df5,df7],axis =1, join_axes=[df.index])


df['openchgprevday']  =   ((df['Open']-1)-(df['Open'])

print("Hello World")
```

This is the error message

```
  File "columnadder.py", line 144
    print("Hello World")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: You're probably using python 2, try `print "Hello world"` (without brackets)

Comment: I am using python 3.5 but I tried it anyway and it won't work

Comment: That isn't be invalid syntax in Python 2 or 3; something else is the matter. You're simply missing a closing parenthesis on the previous line.

Comment: Especially with invalid syntax, it's often helpful to cut down the code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the error.  In this case, you would notice that the line above is necessary, so it must be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extra parenthesis here

```
df['openchgprevday']  =   ((df['Open']-1)-(df['Open'])

print("Hello World")
```

To correct that, do

```
df['openchgprevday']  =   (df['Open']-1)-(df['Open'])

print("Hello World")
```

Comment: You were faster. Good catch!

Comment: Never mind it works I never would have guessed that. It was the parenthesis  thanks I thought it would still work with just a simple hello world even if the code is bad but I guess I learned something new